# Is it possible to set version while generating qr code using zxing lib in android?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

While generating the qr code for android using zxing library is it possible to set the version number like version 4 or any other version .
Any guidance or link would be appreciable .
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes check the EncodedHintType map:

```
private Bitmap stringToQRCode(String text, int width, int height) {
    BitMatrix bitMatrix;
    try {
        HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");
        map.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M); 
        map.put(EncodeHintType.QR_VERSION, 9);  // (1-40)
        map.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 2); // pixels
        bitMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, map);

        int bitMatrixWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int bitMatrixHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[bitMatrixWidth * bitMatrixHeight];

        int colorWhite = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        int colorBlack = 0xFF000000;

        for (int y = 0; y < bitMatrixHeight; y++) {
            int offset = y * bitMatrixWidth;
            for (int x = 0; x < bitMatrixWidth; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? colorBlack : colorWhite;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No. There would be no real point to this. The version can't be lower than what is required to encode the data, and setting it higher just makes a denser QR code that's slightly harder to read.

Comment: what about generating it for version 4(33x33 module)? I tried it with normal java program using com.keepautomation.barcode library and successfully generated that version 4(33x33 module) QR code but is it possible to implement the same in Android?

Comment: can you please guide me to achieve that in android ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The version is set to the lowest possible version that accommodates the data. If that's version 4, version 4 will be used. You need not do anything at all.

Comment: Okay I got your point.According to you version will be set according the data size whatever it takes to occupy it.Thank You