# How to generate QRCode of version 4 (33x33) using any of the libraries?

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I need to generate QR Code of version-4. The current library I use is ZXing's QRCodeWriter which gives me QRCode of version-1 I suppose, if not please correct me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This topic could be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484473/is-it-possible-to-set-version-while-generating-qr-code-using-zxing-lib-in-androi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem--needed to generate a QR Code of version-4 (33 by 33 pixels), at the request of my company.

I'm working in C#, but I believe the idea is the same.  When setting your QrCodeEncodingOptions, you can specify the version:

```
        QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
        {
            DisableECI = true,
            CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            QrVersion = 4
        };
```

Note** The lower the version number, the less data it will be able to contain.  For example, if you set the version to 3 or 4, then try to write a bunch of data into the QR code, an error will be thrown.